# Concatenate jquery variable with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, concatenation

I am caching a selector into a jquery variable, like so:

```
var elem = $('.wrapper');
```

I want to perform different queries on the variable according to certain properties. gt(0), :visible, :hidden etc.

By my reckoning, it should look like this:

```
var elemHidden = $(elem+':hidden');
```

Of course this is not working. I am assuming it is simple, or something quite close to the code I have.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5m7nf97r/

Here is some HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">Wrapper 1</div>
<div class="wrapper">Wrapper 2</div>
etc..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not concatenate a jQuery object and a string. You want to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set.

```
var elemHidden = elem.filter(':hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$.is()` method:

```
elem.is(':hidden');
elem.is(':visible');
elem.is(':checked');
```

And for other specific methods as `$.gt()`

```
elem.gt(0); or $(elem).gt(0)
```

Comment: The `is` method is is going to return a boolean, I do not think that is what OP wants.

Comment: Thank you. This method does work. Or it did in the code I was testing at least.